# Homebrew not allowing results redirection

Tags: bash, macos, homebrew

I am trying to check dates of latest `homebrew` instals on my `Mac` using following command:

```
brew info --installed --json=v2
```

Though I'd like to parse the results later on with `jq` since the output is a `json` document and I simply use:

```
brew info --installed --json=v2 > Results.json
```

However I am getting the following error message:

```
-bash: Results.json: Permission denied
```

Even when I use `touch` before the command line, it is denied.

What am I missing here? Thank you

Comment: This isn't a brew problem. The redirection is done _by your shell_ before it even starts brew. The problem is that you're trying to run this command in a directory you don't have write access to so you can't create the output file.

Comment: Change `> Results.json` to `>~/Results.json` to put the output in your home directory or somewhere else you can definitely write to.